# A Problem About Finite Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group and $H,K \leq G$.

First prove that $\left | \left \langle H,K \right \rangle :K\right |\geq \left | H:H\cap K \right |$.

Then if $\left| H:H\cap K \right |> \frac{1}{2}\left | G:K \right |$ show that $G=\left \langle H,K \right \rangle$.

I really have no idea what should I do to solve them. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

For first one: $|HK|\leq | \langle H,K\rangle |$  and also $|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|K \cap H|}$.

For second one : Show that if $\frac{|G|}{2}<|H|$, then $H=G$.